# File permission with setuid and octal 4000

Tags: chmod, setuid

When we set `setuid` to a file, we do the following in the terminal:

```
chmod u+s filename
```

This works fine. But the octal number 4000 is always associated with setuid (in books etc).

I understand (to some good extent) file permissions, the concept of umask, setuid and using octal numbers with `chmod`. But I still cannot figure out the relationship between the octal number 4000 and setuid. Please explain.

Answer (score 12):

It's just a convention. All constant identifiers are associated with numbers in the Linux source code. Some of them are very old, and come from the very first releases of the kernel while others were added recently.

The constant `S_ISUID` associated with "setuid" is defined in [include/uapi/linux/stat.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/stat.h#L15), one of the numerous Linux headers. It could have been defined to anything but it happened to be 04000.

As stated by @steeldriver, `man 2 stat` can help you understand the meaning of the different constants used for files permission:

```
       S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit fields
       S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
       S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
       S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
       S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
       S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
       S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
       S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
       S_ISUID    0004000   set-user-ID bit
       S_ISGID    0002000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
       S_ISVTX    0001000   sticky bit (see below)
       S_IRWXU    00700     mask for file owner permissions
       S_IRUSR    00400     owner has read permission
       S_IWUSR    00200     owner has write permission
       S_IXUSR    00100     owner has execute permission
       S_IRWXG    00070     mask for group permissions
       S_IRGRP    00040     group has read permission
       S_IWGRP    00020     group has write permission
       S_IXGRP    00010     group has execute permission
       S_IRWXO    00007     mask for permissions for others (not in group)
       S_IROTH    00004     others have read permission
       S_IWOTH    00002     others have write permission
       S_IXOTH    00001     others have execute permission
```

In this excert, you see not only the constants and their numeric value but also the way they are chosen. Developers/designers have chosen the constants in such a way you can *combine* them. For example `S_ISUID and S_IRWXU and S_IRUSR and S_IRGRP = 04740`, so permission `04740` precisely means "setuid and all permissions for owner and read permission for owning group".

Comment: +1 btw on most systems, `man 2 stat` has a discussion of the `stat` structure and its fields (in particular, the `st_mode` value) - slightly more convenient than trawling the header file.

Comment: @steeldriver You're right, I edited my answer. :-)

Comment: I could not find a copy of `man 2 stat` which lists these values. The [Linux kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/stat.h) contains the values without explanation, and [Some](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod) [man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/oldstat) [pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) give an explanation for some of the values. This is a great compilation of info, but is there an actual reference or manual for this somewhere that isn't behind a POSIX paywall?

Answer (score 4):

In most Unix-like systems, a file, directory, or any other filesystem object is represented by an **inode**, which contains, among other things, an integer called the **mode**, which describes the type of object and some of its permissions. It's described in [POSIX stat.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

```
The following symbolic names for the values of type mode_t shall also be defined:

File type:
    S_IFREG
        Regular.
    S_IFDIR
        Directory.
    S_IFLNK
        Symbolic link.

File mode bits:

S_IRWXU
    Read, write, execute/search by owner.

    S_IRUSR
        Read permission, owner.
    S_IWUSR
        Write permission, owner.
    S_IXUSR
        Execute/search permission, owner.
...

S_ISUID
    Set-user-ID on execution.
S_ISGID
    Set-group-ID on execution.
...
```

Those are all symbolic names for integer constants. `S_IFREG` is 0100000. `S_IRUSR` is 000400. `S_ISUID` is 004000. They're in octal for ease of use: the file mode bits can logically be considered to be 4 groups of 3 bits each.

Here you can see the file type bits and file mode bits of my `.profile`:

```
$ perl -e 'printf("%#o\n", (stat(".profile"))[2]);'
0100644
```

Users can set the mode bits (but not the file type) using the `chmod` system call, which takes an integer argument (possibly using some of those S_* symbolic constants), or the `chmod` utility, which takes either an integer or symbolic names (such as `u+r`).

Since, in practice, there are not that many different combinations of mode bits, many Unix users over many decades have called `chmod` (both the system call and the command) with a numeric argument rather than symbolic names. `0755` means "writable by owner, readable and executable to everyone else", `0644` means "writable by owner, readable by everyone else", `04755` means "setuid, writable by owner, readable and executable by everyone else`.

Answer (score 2):

From the (english) man page for `chmod` (debian jessy):
(Highlight by me)

> A numeric mode is from one to four octal digits (0-7), derived by
>   adding up the bits with values 4, 2, and 1.  Omitted digits are
>   assumed to be leading zeros.  **The first digit selects the set user ID
>   (4) and set group  ID  (2)
>          and  restricted  deletion or sticky (1) attributes.**  The second digit selects permissions for the user who owns the file: read (4),
>   write (2), and execute (1); the third selects permissions for other
>   users in the file's group,
>          with the same values; and the fourth for other users not in the file's group, with the same values.

I am not sure if this answers your question, but it does explain what the numbers mean.

Answer (score -1):

You can go through [this link](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-do-i-set-up-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits-on-linux/#:%7E:text=Setuid%2C%20Setgid%20and%20Sticky%20Bits,write%20or%20execute%20the%20file.) for more details about **setuid setgid** and **sticky bit**.

*Setuid, Setgid and Sticky Bits are special types of Unix/Linux file permission sets that permit certain users to run specific programs with elevated privileges.* Ultimately the permissions that are set on a file determine what users can read, write or execute the file. For the *special permissions*, you prepend these numbers with another number where **4 is setuid, 2 is setgid, and 1 is the sticky bit**. The following commands are all the same.

```
root@host [~]#  chmod 4755 myfile
root@host [~]#  chmod u+s myfile
root@host [~]#  ls -l myfile 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 test test 0 Mar 2 17:59 myfile
root@host [~]#
root@host [~]#  chmod 2755 myfile
root@host [~]#  chmod g+s myfile
root@host [~]#  ls -l myfile
-rwxr-sr-x 1 test test 0 Mar 2 17:59 myfile
root@host [~]#  
root@host [~]#  chmod 1755 mydir
root@host [~]#  chmod +t mydir
root@host [~]#  ls -ld mydir
drwxr-sr-t 2 test test2 4096 Mar 2 19:59 mydir
root@host [~]#
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything on top of the earlier answers. Also it's much better to post text as text rather than as an image. Among other things, it lets the readers decide on the fonts and colors they want to use. See: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Sure I will change the image to text. I tried in my own way to write the answer. Because I thought we need to show **u+s** and **4755** alongside to make it more clear. Just like this one...
`chmod 4755 myfile
chmod u+s myfile`
When I was first learning, this both helped me to understand this quickly.